# Clicking outside the React takes you back to the main source page

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

My problem is In my Main source page when i open one modal from that i will open another modal when i will click outside second modal then it would redirect me to main source page not in parent modal which is default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the state of the second modal on the handling close of the first modal.

but if you share your code, we can better find the reason of this bug.